# PHP - Calculating a bitmask from an amount

Tags: php, math, networking, bit-manipulation

I need to calculate the bitmask for N number of IPs.. I know from memory that:

```
32 = 1 IP
31 = 2 IP
30 = 4 IP
29 = 8 IP
```

and so on..

If i require 8 Ip's, that is equal to POW(2, 3) = 8; I however start with the 8 and need to work it out backwards.

What would be the best way to calculate this in PHP?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$bitsrequired = ceil(log($number_of_ips) / log(2));
```

Comment: Comes out the same, I just like writing out the division explicitly.

Comment: Aight, my math is a bit rusty (note to self: brush up...), so I was actually wondering ;) Good to reacquaint  myself with those 2 being equal.

Comment: I don't understand logarithms, so i was avoiding it :), but the solution works as well as any..

Comment: one way of thinking about them: logs are to multiplication as multiplication is to addition. converting to log operations reduces exponentiation to simple multiplication, as multiplication reduces to simple repeated addition.